# How to fill StringValue in protobuf in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

How to fill StringValue in protobuf (programming in python)

```
message event {
    string id = 1; 
    google.protobuf.StringValue test = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
event.test.value = 'test'
```

Also works. It is more straightforward and doesn't require importing `StringValue` class.

Answer (score 3):

After fighting for a while found the answer

```
event.test.CopyFrom(wrappers.StringValue(value='test'))
```